# Print data from For angular js (ionic framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to print a variable which is inside a for cycle. This is my code
in this part I save in a variable my $scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre. When I print in an alert the $scope.NombTuto I get the data but I want to print in my html page.

```
MostrarTuto.servicioMostrarTuto().success(function(data){
    $scope.datosTuto=data;
    var TamanioURI = $scope.datosTuto.length;
    for ( i=43; i < TamanioURI; i++) {  
      if ($scope.nom_coe == $scope.datosTuto[i].Residencia){
        $scope.NombTuto=$scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre;
        alert($scope.NombTuto+" ...");
      };
    };
  })
```

this is my html page

```
<div class="list card">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
          <h2>Nombre: {{i.Nombre}}</h2>
          <h2>Horario: {{i.Sexo}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
```

Only I want to print this $scope.NombTuto that please Help me... thanks

Comment: Is datosTuto an object or array? Can you give us an example of the structure of datosTuto?

Comment: is array. Actually in my html I get all the data which is in the json but I want to print $scope.NombTuto  because this variable gets data from a specific variable

Comment: Could please share a sample structure of datosTuto

Comment: [{"id":"1","fecha_trama":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:21:12"},{"id":"2","fecha_trama":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:22:42","Cliente":"1"},{"id":"3","fecha_trama":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:25:34","Cliente":"1","Cedula":"1103456789"}] 
something like this..

Answer (score 0):

Define $scope.NombTuto outside the function. You may get access.

```
$scope.NombTuto = '';
MostrarTuto.servicioMostrarTuto().success(function(data){
    $scope.datosTuto=data;
    var TamanioURI = $scope.datosTuto.length;
    for ( i=43; i < TamanioURI; i++) {  
      if ($scope.nom_coe == $scope.datosTuto[i].Residencia){
        $scope.NombTuto=$scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre;
        alert($scope.NombTuto+" ...");
      };
    };
  })
```

In html

```
Matched value : {{NombTuto}}
<div class="list card">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
          <h2>Nombre: {{i.Nombre}}</h2>
          <h2>Horario: {{i.Sexo}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
```

Updated answerfor NumbTuto as array

```
$scope.nom_coe = 'test';
$scope.NombTuto = [];
$scope.NombTutoStr = '';
$scope.datosTuto=
    [
        {"id":"1","fecha_trama":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:21:12", "Residencia" : 'test', "Nombre" : "Nombre1"},
        {"id":"2","fecha_‌​trama":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:22:42","Cliente":"1", "Residencia" : 'test1', "Nombre" : "Nombre2"},
        {"id":"3","fecha_trama‌​":"2015-07-08","hora_trama":"08:25:34","Cliente":"1","Cedula":"1103456789", "Residencia" : 'test', "Nombre" : "Nombre3"}
    ];
var TamanioURI = $scope.datosTuto.length;
for ( i=0; i < TamanioURI; i++) {  
  if ($scope.nom_coe == $scope.datosTuto[i].Residencia){
    $scope.NombTuto[$scope.datosTuto[i].id]=$scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre;
    $scope.NombTutoStr = $scope.NombTutoStr ? $scope.NombTutoStr +","+$scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre
                        : $scope.datosTuto[i].Nombre;
    alert($scope.NombTuto[$scope.datosTuto[i].id]+" ...");
  };
};
```

html

```
<div class="list card">
        Matched values : {{NombTutoStr}}
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
            <h3>Nombre: {{i.Nombre}}</h3>
            <h3>Horario: {{i.Sexo}}</h3>
            <div>
                <p ng-show="NombTuto[i.id]">NombTuto :: {{NombTuto[i.id]}}</p>
            </div>
            ---------------------------------------------------------------
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>            
    </div>
```

Comment: In my code I have access, but When I print NombTuto in my page html only shows me the last value from my json. 

My idea is to print data like my alert, in my html page

Comment: If you have multiple matches, use an array for NombTuto to map with the corresponding field. I updated my answer. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks but I solved it ....
only in my html page I used an if like this:

ng-repeat="i in datosTuto | filter:busqueda" 
             ng-if="i.Residencia == nom_coe"